# how to let django achieve inner join

Tags: python, django

there are two tables:

```
class TBLUserProfile(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    relmusicuid = models.IntegerField()
    fansnum = models.IntegerField()

class TSinger(models.Model):
   fsinger_id = models.IntegerField()
   ftbl_user_profile = models.ForeignKey(TBLUserProfile, db_column='Fsinger_id')
```

I want to get Tsinger info and then order by TBLUserProfile.fansnum, I know how to write sql query: `select * from t_singer INNER JOIN tbl_user_profile ON (tbl_user_profile.relmusicuid=t_singer.Fsinger_id)  order by tbl_user_profile.fansnum`, but I don't want to use model raw function. `relmusicuid` is not primary key otherwise I can use ForeignKey to let it work. How can I use django model to achieve this？

Comment: I don't understand your question. Also, there seems to be some flaw in your Model structure.

Comment: I want to get TSinger infomation and order by TBLUserProfile's fansnum, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
Tsinger.objects.all().order_by('ftbl_user_profile__fansnum')
```

For information about Django JOIN :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: I have try this, but this code translate to sql is `select * from t_singer INNER JOIN tbl_user_profile ON (tbl_user_profile.userid =t_singer.Fsinger_id)  order by tbl_user_profile.fansnum` , because relmusicuid is not primary_key, it dose not work

Comment: I don't understand...I think your Model does not match with what you want. Could you explain what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: simply put, I want to achieve sql:`select * from t_singer INNER JOIN tbl_user_profile ON (tbl_user_profile.relmusicuid=t_singer.Fsinger_id)  order by tbl_user_profile.fansnum` , it means  only when `tbl_user_profile.relmusicuid is equal to t_singer.Fsinger_id`, show the order result. In your way, the sql will be when `tbl_user_profile.userid is equal to t_singer.Fsinger_id`, why this happen is that the relmusicuid is not primary key,if relmusicuid is primary key in models,your code works,but it is not primary key.